# Is it possible to print HTTP Response inside addBodyEndHandler()?

Tags: http, url-routing, vert.x

I am trying to add log entries during start and as soon as request is responded (using `ctx.addBodyEndHandler`).

In below function `foo` what should be `aaa`?

```
  private void foo(io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.RoutingContext ctx) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String uuid = ctx.get("RequestIdentifier");
    String clientAddress = ctx.request().remoteAddress().host();
    LOG.info("Request ID: {}. Client IP: {}. Application type: {}. HTTP Method: {}. Body {}. Processing route: {}", uuid, clientAddress, this.getClientDescription(ctx.request()), ctx.request().method(), this.getRequestBody(ctx), ctx.request().uri());

    ctx.addBodyEndHandler(ign -> {
      LOG.info("Request ID: {} completed in {} ms. Response {}. Response code {}.", uuid, System.currentTimeMillis() - start, aaa, ctx.response().getStatusCode());
    });

    // more logic
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the response body from the `RoutingContext`. Some responses may be very large so Vert.x doesn't store them.

If you are confident it will not harm your production system, you can store the body payload as context data before sending it:

```
routingContext.put("responseBody", content);
routingContext.response.end(content);
```

Then retrieve it in the `bodyEnd` handler:

```
String aaa = routingContext.get("responseBody");
```